# Optical flow from velocity components

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, simulation, opticalflow

I have the simulation data which contains the velocity values (x, y and z components), as well as density and energy values for each voxel. Is it possible to obtain the optical flow from the velocities, which will be the ground truth?

I tried the following:

```
data = np.fromfile('Velocity/ns_1000_v.dat', dtype=np.float32)
data = np.reshape(data,(128, 128, 128, 3)) # 3D volumes

slice_num = 5 # let's pick up a slice
vx = data[:,:,slice_num,0]
vy = data[:,:,slice_num,1]

hsv = np.zeros((128,128,3), dtype=np.uint8)
hsv[..., 1] = 255

mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(vx, vy)
hsv[..., 0] = ang * 180 / np.pi / 2
hsv[..., 2] = cv2.normalize(mag, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

bgr = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
```

This doesn't show the (2D) flow, which I expected to see.

I already calculated the optical flow from the density values (in an unsupervised setup) and now wanted to compare with the ground truth. An example of the computed flow looks like this:
[Computed unsupervised flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmwtb.png)

Thank you!

Comment: The question is very vague. What have you tried so far? Do you have a minimal code example to share?

Comment: I tried to convert the 2D velocity components (vx and vy) of the simulation data directly to flow using HSV color model. Adding the code.